# Is there a record of merged questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, merged-questions

I have asked a total of two questions on meta.stackoverflow, yet under my profile it shows zero questions. One of those questions got around 8 up votes and I still have my reputation from them, this question happened to be very close to another question and it seems the answers to this question got transferred to another one. I was just wondering if there is, or should there be a way to notify people as to what happened because I was and still am confused as to exactly what happened.

**edit:** Here is the [link to the other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5873/superusers-questions-with-an-accepted-answer-color). I was able to find this because my votes on the answers that were originally on my question transferred as well.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question that now has your answers?

Comment: added link to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now handle question merging in a much more sane way -- both questions are retained, one is a stub, and all answers are migrated into the merged question. If the stub is deleted, we 301 redirect to the merge target.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only record that a question was merged is found in the [revision list of the master question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5873/list). Though the answers, comments, votes, etc are moved over to the master, the duplicate question itself is excised from the system (not even moderators can see it anymore).

In other words, merging two questions is a fairly dramatic process, and we do our best to do it as sparingly as possible. My guess is that in your case, Jeff wanted to consolidate the similar feature requests so he could mark it all as completed.

While I agree that the process lacks transparency, I'm not sure what sort of notification would work to let the duplicate author know that their question was merged into another one. Maybe a locked, answerless 'stub' should be left behind with a link to the master question similar to the cross-site migration operation?